# jQuery carousel slider autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a simple jQuery carousel slider and I want it to auto play and when been hovered upon it should pause but i cant achieve that.

And here is the code of the jQuery slider and i need it to autoplay and pause on hover:

**Css**

```
     .image-shown{
    display: inline-block;
     }
.image-hidden{
    display: none;
}
.carousel-inner{
    width: 750px;
    height: 300px;
    float: left;
}
.carousel-inner img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.previouslink, .nextlink{
    float: left;
    margin-top:150px;
}
.previouslink{
    margin-right:20px;
}
.nextlink{
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
    <title>slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

</head>
<body>
<div class="page">
        <h2>jQuery IMAGE</h2>

        <div class="carousel-outer"> 
            <a href="#" class="previouslink">Previous</a>
                <div class="carousel-inner"> 
                    <img class="image-shown imagess" src="img/bridge.jpg" alt="" />
                    <img class="image-hidden imagess" src="img/cool.jpg" alt="" />
                    <img class="image-hidden imagess" src="img/house.jpg" alt="" />
                    <img class="image-hidden imagess" src="img/lion.jpg" alt="" />
                    <img class="image-hidden imagess" src="img/nature.jpg" alt="" />
                </div>
            <a href="#" class="nextlink">Next</a>
        </div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My custom jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".nextlink").on("click", function(e){

            var currentActiveImage = $(".image-shown");
            var nextActiveImage = currentActiveImage.next();

            if(nextActiveImage.length == 0){
                nextActiveImage= $(".carousel-inner img").first();
            }

            currentActiveImage.removeClass("image-shown").addClass("image-hidden").css("z-index", -10);
            nextActiveImage.addClass("image-shown").removeClass("image-hidden").css("z-index", 20);
            $(".carousel-inner img").not([currentActiveImage, nextActiveImage]).css("z-index", 1);
            e.preventDefault();

    });

        $(".previouslink").on("click", function(e){
            var currentActiveImage = $(".image-shown");
            var nextActiveImage = currentActiveImage.prev();

            if(nextActiveImage.length == 0){
                nextActiveImage= $(".carousel-inner img").last();
            }

            currentActiveImage.removeClass("image-shown").addClass("image-hidden").css("z-index", -10);
            nextActiveImage.addClass("image-shown").removeClass("image-hidden").css("z-index", 20);
            $(".carousel-inner img").not([currentActiveImage, nextActiveImage]).css("z-index", 1);
            e.preventDefault();

        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){ 
    $('.jcarousel').jcarousel();
    $('.jcarousel').jcarouselAutoscroll({
        interval: 1000,
        target: '+=1'
    })
});
```

I think you can use the [Autoscroll plugin](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/docs/plugins/autoscroll/)